# PHP if...else... statement returning error

Tags: php, if-statement

Below is my code

```
        <?php
//Vars
$alreadylogged = 0;
$username = 0;
//End Var
//Start Script
print 'Welcome to CraftedList!</br>'
if ($alreadylogged=="1") *Side note, this line is line 34*
{
    print 'You are currently logged in as'. $username .'!';
}
else
{
    print 'You are not logged in!'
}
    ?>
```

But when I execute it on a localhost XAMPP client, it returns this error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptest\index.php on line 34

I checked on W3 Schools and my code is similar to theirs.

Comment: The faster you stop using W3Schools the better off you'll be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a `;`

```
print 'Welcome to CraftedList!</br>';
                                    ^ here
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed a simple mistake...

Comment: @user1185220 Also missing a semicolon on the `print 'You are not logged in!'` line.

Comment: @Pang Right, I didn't even read that far down...

Answer (score 2):

missing **;**

here:

```
print 'Welcome to CraftedList!</br>'
```

and here:

```
print 'You are not logged in!'
```